# Atomic multiplication and division?

Tags: cuda

There is atomicAdd and atomicSub but it seems that atomicMul and atomicDiv don't exist! Is it possible? I need to implement the following code:

```
 atomicMul(&accumulation[index],value)
```

How Can I do?

Comment: The Programming Guide has an [Example](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions) how to express arbitrary atomic operations in terms of `atomicCAS()`.

Comment: @tera if you want to write ann answer I would upvote

Comment: I saw the example. It implements the atomicAdd for double, but it not implements a new atomic arithmetic operator. Is it easy to modify this example to create the atomicMul? How? Do I have to substitute the plus symbol + with wildcard *?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solved. But I cannot understand how atomicMul works and I don't know how to write it for floats.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

__device__ double atomicMul(double* address, double val) 
{ 
  unsigned long long int* address_as_ull = (unsigned long long int*)address; 
  unsigned long long int old = *address_as_ull, assumed; 
  do { 
 assumed = old; 
 old = atomicCAS(address_as_ull, assumed, __double_as_longlong(val * __longlong_as_double(assumed))); 
 } while (assumed != old); return __longlong_as_double(old);
}      
__global__ void try_atomicMul(double* d_a, double* d_out)
{
     atomicMul(d_out,d_a[threadIdx.x]);
} 
int main()
{
  double h_a[]={5,6,7,8}, h_out=1;
  double *d_a, *d_out;

 cudaMalloc((void **)&d_a, 4 * sizeof(double));
 cudaMalloc((void **)&d_out,sizeof(double));

 cudaMemcpy(d_a, h_a, 4 * sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
 cudaMemcpy(d_out, &h_out, sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

 dim3 blockDim(4);
 dim3 gridDim(1);

  try_atomicMul<<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(d_a,d_out);
 cudaMemcpy(&h_out, d_out, sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

 printf("%f \n",h_out);
 cudaFree(d_a);
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll supplement horus' answer based on what I understood about `atomicCAS`. My answer can be wrong in detail, because I  didn't look inside the `atomicCAS` function but just read the documents about it ([atomicCAS](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomiccas), [Atomic Functions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions)). Feel free to tackle my answer.

**How atomicMul works**

According to my understanding, the behavior of `atomicCAS(int* address, int compare, int val)` is following.

1. Copy `*address` into `old` (i.e `old  = *address`)
2. Store `(old == compare ? val : old)` to `*address`. (At this point, the value of `old` and `*address` can be different depending on if the condition matched or not.)
3. Return `old`

Understanding about its behavior gets better when we look at the `atomicMul` function's definition together.

```
unsigned long long int* address_as_ull = (unsigned long long int*)address; 
unsigned long long int oldValue = *address_as_ull, assumed; // Modified the name 'old' to 'oldValue' because it can be confused with 'old' inside the atomicCAS. 
do { 
  assumed = oldValue; 
  // other threads can access and modify value of *address_as_ull between upper and lower line. 
  oldValue = atomicCAS(address_as_ull, assumed, __double_as_longlong(val * 
                       __longlong_as_double(assumed))); 
} while (assumed != oldValue); return __longlong_as_double(oldValue);
```

What we want to do is read the value from `address`(its value is eqaul to `address_as_ull`), and multiply some value to it and then write it back. The problem is other threads can access and modify value of `*address` between read, modify, and write.

To ensure there was no intercept of other threads, we check if the value of `*address` is equal to what we `assumed` to be there. Say that other thread modified value of `*address` after `assumed=oldValue` and `oldValue = atomicCAS(...)`. The modified value of `*address` will be copied to `old` variable inside the `atomicCAS`(see behavior 1. of `atomicCAS` above). 
 Since `atomicCAS` updates `*address` according to `*address = (old == compare ? val : old)`, `*address` won't be changed (`old==*address`).

Then `atomicCAS` returns `old` and it goes into `oldValue` so that the loop can keep going and we can try another shot at next iteration. When `*address`is not modified between read and write, then `val` is written to the `*address` and loop will end.

**How to write it for float**

short answer :

```
__device__ float atomicMul(float* address, float val) 
{ 
  int* address_as_int = (int*)address; 
  int old = *address_as_int, assumed; 
  do { 
    assumed = old; 
    old = atomicCAS(address_as_int, assumed, __float_as_int(val * 
__float_as_int(assumed))); 
 } while (assumed != old); return __int_as_float(old);
}
```

*I didn't test it, so there can be some errors. Fix me if I'm wrong.*

**How does it work :**
For some reason, `atomicCAS` only supports integer types. So we should manually convert float/double type variable into integer type to input to the function and then re-convert the integer result to `float`/`double` type. What I've modified above is `double` to `float` and `unsigned long long` to `int` because the size of `float` matches to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Kyungsu's answer was almost correct. On the line defining old == atomicCAS(...) though, he used __float_as_int when he should have used __int_as_float. I corrected his code below:

```
__device__ float atomicMul(float* address, float val){
//Implementation of atomic multiplication
//See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354798/atomic-multiplication-and-division
int* address_as_int = (int*)address;
int old = *address_as_int;
int assumed;
do {
    assumed = old;
    old = atomicCAS(address_as_int, assumed, __float_as_int(val * __int_as_float(assumed)));
} while (assumed != old); 
return __int_as_float(old);}
```

Comment: You can use `this` to markup code inline.